# SharePoint 2010 Licensing with 10k employees

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, licensing

I am doing my homework and I need to get rough costs for licensing SharePoint 2010 for company with 10,000 employees. I made an assumption that a company runs on Windows Server R2. The SharePoint 2010 prerequisite that has to be purchased is only SQL Server 2008.

I looked up at http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/mla/ and quick quote asks me to enter quantity. 1. What quatity do I need to enter to SQL Server 2008, just 1 is enough for a company with 10,000 people.
2. For the SharePoint Enterprise CAL I entered quantity 10000 and get the result ~$1,250,000.00.

Can somebody help me with number of SQL Sever required in this solution? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft licensing can seem complicated if you are doing that for the first time and I would advise you to contact a licensing specialist in your country/region that can help you optimize for best price and licensing deals. For a company of 10000 people you should not be checking these prices online, you need to talk to licensing specialist! Chances are you are already licensed for most of the stuff you need, and you might have to pay just a few server licenses.

To license this you need: SharePoint, Windows and SQL licenses.

**SharePoint** is licensed *per server*, and *per user - (Client Access License - CAL)*. In short you will have to pay:

```
Total_Cost = NumberOfServers * SharePoint_Server_Price + NumberOfUsers * SharePoint_Standard_CAL_Price
```

If you plan to deploy SharePoint Enterprise Features the equation is as follows:

```
Total_Cost = NumberOfServers * SharePoint_Server_Price + NumberOfUsers * (SharePoint_Standard_CAL_Price + SharePoint_Enterprise_CAL_Price)
```

There are two modes of **SQL** (2012) Licensing: Server + CAL or Processor Core based licenses. Your cost is:

```
 Total_SQL_Cost = NumberOfServers * SQL_Server_Price + NumberOfUsers * SQL_CAL_Price
```

If you plan to purchase Core based licensing the equation is as follows:

```
Total_SQL_Cost = NumberOfProcessorCores * SQL_Core_Price
```

Please note: SharePoint CALs and SQL CALs are usually part of [CAL suites](http://www.microsoft.com/calsuites/en/us/products/default.aspx) available as part of your Enterprise Agreement with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

SQL capacity planning is more dependent on data amount. How many documents and items you expect? What total files size you want to put there? What content size grow ratio will be?

I would say there should be no less than 2 SQL boxes, most likely 4-8. More if you need failover.